# Laravel 5 Eloquent select items in Table 1 that dont have relation in table 2 when table 2 id = x

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am trying to find a method similar to has() that would allow me to do following:

Select all users from users that doesntHave link with subscriptions table when subscriptions.id = x

user might have a link with subscription.id = 1, subscription.id = 2 but not 3. So i want to exclude users that already have a link with subscription table when subscription entry under question has id of X

users table:
user1 has access to subscr1 and subscr2
user2 has no links
user3 has link to subscr1

subscr table:
subscr1
subscr2
subscr3

so when i want to get a list of users that dont have a link with item subscr3 from subscr table I would expect to see user2 and user3

Comment: If you put something in sqlfidde it would make it easier to help you http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get this via a relation in this way:

```
// User model
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription');
}

public function hasSubscription(Subscription $subscription)
{
    return (bool)$this->subscriptions()
        ->where('subscription_id', $subscription->id)
        ->first();
}
```

Usage:

```
if($user->hasSubscription($subscription)) {
    // User has subscription
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [whereDoesntHave](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave), assumed you've setup relation like this in your `App\User` model:

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
$subscriptionId = 3;
$users = User::whereDoesntHave('subscriptions', function($q) use($subscriptionId) {
    $q->where('subscriptions.id', $subscriptionId);
})
->get();
```